# Fix the alignment of two child divs

Tags: css, html, alignment, margin

The project is to create a micro-blogging website similar to Twitter. I chose to name the site Chirper (how clever of me). Each post is structured by a parent div, an avatar div and a content div. The avatar and content divs are displayed inline, but they are not aligned properly. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="chirp">
<div class="chirp_avatar_region">
    <img src="img/avatar/default.png" alt="Avatar" width="64" height="64">
</div>
<div class="chirp_content">
    <p>
        <a href="users.php?uid=15">USER</a>
        <span class="timeStamp">2013-11-22 16:43:59</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        COMMENT
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="repost.php?cid=24">ReChirp!</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The div's aren't aligned how I want them to be (level and 100% of the parent).

I can't post images, so here is a link to an imgur page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2tP.jpg

Relevant CSS:

```
    body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #666;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* Containers */

div {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #000;

    padding: 10px;
}

div.pane {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: 0099FF;
}

div.chirp {
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    width: 80%;

    padding: 5px;
}

div.chirp_avatar_region {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;

    text-align: center;

    /*border-style: none;*/
}

div.chirp_content {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

    /*border-style: none;*/
}

div.chirp_avatar_region > img, div.chirp_content > p {
    margin-top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Issue #1 (uneven alignment) has been solved with the vertical-align property.

Comment: Issue #2 (child div not occupying full height of parent) still hasn't been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can either float your inner divs then clear the float following the container

or

use vertical-align:top to position your divs at the top of the container

Comment: The vertical align property did solve issue #1. Although, both divs still aren't occupying the full height of their parent. Any advice?

Comment: You need to set a height for the parent container in order for height:100% to work. This will also cause problems as you have padding set for these divs which combined with a height of 100%, will push them outside their parent container - http://jsfiddle.net/Jq96K/

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but what I think is happening is that by defining position:inline-block, it's putting them on the same line, and making the line-height the height of the chirp_content container.   In a sense anyway. 
Set to vertical-align:top; and it should solve it.

Ex.

```
.chirp_content, .chirp_avatar_region{ vertical-align:top; }
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EMCm/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Give to the avatar_region a float: left, and remove its width: and height: setting. Remove the chirp_content div, it circumvents the inlining.

Comment: You really shouldn't include a plug to upvote in your answer, if you have to do so, maybe do it in a comment...

Comment: @DrCord Finally I did it. Sorry. :-)